# How to combine two lists with different properties based on a condition in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

i have two lists -plans and divisions with different properties ..
Sample data:

```
    {
        "plans": [
            {
                "planCode": "A",
                "planShortName": "Apple",
                "planType": null,
                "bisPlanCode": "878",

            },
            {
                "planCode": "B",
                "planShortName": "Ball",
                "planType": null,
                "bisPlanCode": "536",

            }
        ],
        "divisions": [
            {
                "planCode": "878",
                "divisions": [
      { divisionCode: "2", divisionName: "test2" }, 
            { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "test1" }]
            },
            {
                "planCode": "536",
                "divisions": [
      { divisionCode: "3", divisionName: "test3" }, 
            { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "test1" }
    ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

How to combine both these lists- plans and divsions into one list planDivisions on a condition where plans.bisPlanCode == divisions.plansCode in C#.
so the final result should look like

```
     "planDivisions": [
            {
                "planCode": "A",
                "planShortName": "Apple",
                "planType": null,
                "bisPlanCode": "878",
                "divisions": [ { divisionCode: "2", divisionName: "test2" }, 
            { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "test1" }]

            },
            {
                "planCode": "B",
                "planShortName": "Ball",
                "planType": null,
                "bisPlanCode": "536",
                "divisions": [
{ divisionCode: "3", divisionName: "test3" }, 
        { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "test1"

 }]

            }
    ]
```

What i have tried to do :

```
    List<Data> planDivisions = new List<Data>();

                    Divisions.ForEach(division =>
                    {
                        var plan = Plans.Find(p => p.PlanCode == division.PlanCode);
                        if (plan != null)
                        {
                            Data data = new Data();
                            data.DivisionData = division;
                            data.PlanData = plan;
                            planDivisions.Add(data);
                        }

                    });
```

Is there any effecient way to do ?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've already tried. So far your question is just some json.

Comment: You can use LINQ and join the two lists like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins. Of course, you need to deserialize the JSON first.

Comment: added the code snippet i have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to join both data lists. More about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins).

```
class Plan {
  public int PlanCode { get; set; }
  public string PlanShortName { get; set; }
}

class Division {
  public int DivisionCode { get; set; }
  public string DivisionName { get; set; }
}

class DivisionAssignment {
  public int PlanCode { get; set; }
  public List<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
}

public static void JoinExample() {
  // do your deserialization stuff here
  List<Plan> plans = ...;
  List<DivisionAssignment> assignments = ...;

  // join the data
  var query = from plan in plans
              join assignment in assignments on plan.PlanCode equals assignment.PlanCode
              select new { PlanCode = plan.PlanCode, Divisions = assignment.Divisions };

  // reach the joined data
  foreach (var planDivision in query) {
    ... = planDivision.PlanCode;
    ... = planDivision.Divisions;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yep this helps . Thanks!